# How to pull information in Wordpress without a loop?

Tags: php, wordpress, loops

I'm using a custom post type, and pulling that information throughout the site via a loop. It seems unnecessary to create a loop every time I want to call information from the custom post type. Is there another way?

Here's an example of what the loop looks like, and how I call it.

```
<?php

    $args = 'post_type=post-custom&order=ASC';
    query_posts($args);
    if ( have_posts($args) ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
    $my_meta = get_post_meta($post->ID,'_my_meta',TRUE);
?>

<img src="<?php echo $my_meta['img'];?>">

<?php   
    endwhile; 
    endif;
?>
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: wordpress is a blogging platform. therefore its entire mentality is "everything is a blog", which means multiple posts on a page, which means a loop - even if you only ever want to print one thing.

Comment: Okay, good to know. I just wanted to make sure I wasn't writing extra code for no reason if there was a simpler way.

Comment: Even if you grabbed an array of the posts, you would still need to iterate over them with a loop. I believe you must iterate for what you're looking to do.

Comment: Wait how else wold you get information from your db and show them whitout a loop? I mean you do a sql select, fetch the data and make a loop to show it. Or am i missing something? Is just one post?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use *some* kind of loop...If you don't want to use [The Loop](https://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop), you can use a standard `foreach` loop and [`get_posts()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts). Because you're only interested in getting post meta, you can use the `fields` argument to return an array of post IDs, instead of full post objects:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'post-custom',
    'order' => 'ASC',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'fields' => 'ids'
);
$post_ids = get_posts( $args );

foreach ( $post_ids as $id ) {
    $meta = get_post_meta( $id, '_my_meta', true );
    echo '<img src="' . $meta['img'] . '">';
}
```

As a final note, you should basically [never use `query_posts()`](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/1753/when-should-you-use-wp-query-vs-query-posts-vs-get-posts).

Comment: Excellent, I didn't know there was anything negative around `query_posts()`. I implemented this into my site and it worked great. Thanks for the prompt answer.